# Optimize this validation and initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a very special solution on a Rails 4.2 website where I have many complicated calculations. The problems I have consider validation and initialization.

I create a separate class for each calculation and all look virtually the same way, as can be seen below (code simplified to be easier to overlook). I am out a bit on thin ice here since I have not done anything like this before and some of it is "trial and error programming" but it works.

I am using the code in controllers etc using PUT requests like this:

```
C_9.calculate_me(params)
```

where params could look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "start_date"=>"2016-08-20", "nbr_of_days"=>"90", "commit"=>"Calculate", "controller"=>"calculations", "action"=>"result", "id"=>"9"}
```

## The code

```
class C_9
  include ActiveModel::Validations  
  include ValidationFunctions     

  attr_accessor :start_date, :nbr_of_days
  validates_length_of :start_date, :minimum => 8, :message => "value_is_not_a_proper_date"  
  validates_numericality_of :nbr_of_days, :greater_than => 0, :message => "value_must_be_number_over_zero"
    validate :validate_buggy_start_date   

  def initialize(params = {}, options = {}) 
    @start_date = params[:start_date]
    @nbr_of_days = params[:nbr_of_days]
  end 

  def calculate_me(params)
    @start_date = @start_date.to_date

      result_date = @start_date +  @nbr_of_days.day    
  end   

end
```

## Validation functions

These are validation functions that are common for many different calculations.

```
    def validate_buggy_start_date # Don't know why the validate_start_date will not work for this...
        errors.add(:start_date, 'value_is_not_a_proper_date') unless validate_date(start_date)
    end

  def validate_date(this_date)
    begin
      Date.parse(this_date)
      this_date.to_date
    rescue
      proper_date = false
    else   
      proper_date = true
    end
```

end

## What I need help with

The system is working but there are certain issues I need to optimize:

1. Is there any way I can validate a date in ValidationFunction without having to create a new function (like `def validate_buggy_start_date`) for every date that is named differently. Is there any way I can use the `validate_date()`-function right away from C_9 (i.e. without having to go through validate_buggy_start_date)?
2. I would like to initialize the parameters and at the same time make sure they are float/string/date etc with for example `variable.to_date`. I can't, however, since the initialization is done before the validations so it will crash the app. I now solve it by re-establishing them in the `calculate_me()`-function but it does not feel very DRY. Is there any way around this?
3. For some reason that I cannot understand I need to name the variables exactly like the attribute name, for example `@nbr_of_days` needs to be named just that. If I name it `@day_numbers` it will not work (the value will not be set). Why is it so? Is there a smarter way around it?

In short, please help me make this functionality smarter and more DRY, if possible!

Comment: The answer to your third point is due to the `attr_accessor` which creates the setter and getter methods for `start_date` and `nbr_of_days`

Comment: I see, thanks, is there a  better way to solve this or does the code look optimized to you?

Comment: For now I have no other ideas to implement it, so it looks optimized to me.

Comment: Please bear in mind the following: 1) Stack Overflow uses a Q&A format, which means asking about one issue per question (as opposed to three); this rule makes searching for answers much easier -- you're not the only user here; 2) Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems, not code review; there's a separate code review site; 3) "97% of the time premature optimization is the root of all evil..." You say your code works, so what leads you to believe you have anything you "need" to optimize?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The reason for asking three questions was that they were all related to the same code issue. I have chosen a certain setup (creating classes for Calculations) that is a setup that "works" but has caused other issues because I feel that my solution is more of a "hack" and I believe there could be a smarter way of doing this. I could boil it down to question #1 if that would make it more of a Q&A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending SteveTurczyn's answer: (without patching into ActiveRecord::Base)

You can create custom validators for ActiveRecord models. [See the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

So in your case this would be a solution:

```
# app/models/date_validator.rb
class DateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    Date.parse(value.to_s)
  rescue ArgumentError
    record.errors[attribute] << "value_is_not_a_proper_date"
  end
end
```

And then use the validator in your model:

```
# app/models/c_9.rb
class C_9
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with DateValidator, attributes: [:start_date]
end
```

Example usage:

```
c = C_9.new(start_date: "2016-12-12", end_date: "2014-01-22")
c.valid? # => false
c.start_date # => Mon, 12 Dec 2016 (Date object)
c.other_date = "2016-07-23"
c.valid? # => true
c.other_date # => Sat, 23 Jul 2016
```

Comment: A "bonus question": Would it be possible to put several validations in a DateValidator model like this? If I, e.g. want, to check if an integer is really an integer and use the "DateValidator" model, would that be possible? Or do I have to create another model for each special validation I do?

Comment: No you really should create another validator to validate other thing to keep it clean and don't break the single responsibility

Comment: Thanks...and sorry, forgot about that. Just did the upvote and the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own validations, not just a validation method.  That will let you do...

```
validates_buggy_date :start_date, :end_date, :other_date
```

create a file config/initializers/validates_buggy_date.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.validates_buggy_date(*columns)
    validates_each(columns, {}) do |record, attribute, value|
      begin
        Date.parse(value)
        value.to_date
      rescue
        record.errors[attribute] << 'value_is_not_a_proper_date'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this particular answer does not work though (it does not recognize validates_buggy_date => undefined method `validates_buggy_date'). I have restarted the system and copy-pasted this exactly. I did not realize one could create custom validations so this was interesting anyway. Still, I would love if you could see if there is anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Hmm... works for me.  in my sample app I added the `config/initializers/validates_buggy_date.rb` as above, and in my Vehicle model I did...  `validates_buggy_date :registration_date`   When I do `rails c` I can then do `v = Vehicle.new` and then `v.valid?` and then if I do `v.errors.full_messages` I see `["Registration date value_is_not_a_proper_date"]` so it seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: The file IS in `config/initializers/validates_buggy_date.rb` ??  It's EXACTLY as I coded it above?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the fact that C_9 does not inherit from ActiveRecord:Base (there is no underlying database table), as seen in my code. I tried this in a test app and it worked there. Is there a workaround to it? Btw, I have copy-pasted it and the code is 100% the same.

Comment: Ah of course!  Can you try the same code but change the first line to...`ActiveModel::Validations.class_eval do` ?

Comment: Is there no way I can use my ValidationFunctions-module for this? Thank you so much for helping, by the way.

Comment: Steve, you already been really helpful but have you got any other idea that can help me forward?

Comment: @Christoffer see my answer, hope it helps.